# Can I legally drive in France with an Indian driving licence?

Tags: france, driving, road-trips, driving-licenses

I am travelling to France for a week during summer vacations and I'm planning to do a road trip with the family. Do I need to get an IDP, or is a valid Indian driving licence sufficient? I'll be applying for a Schengen visa in a month or two.

BTW, I drive in US with my Indian licence when I go there on business visa, and it's okay there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Legally](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1459), for visitors, a foreign driving license is enough *provided it is written in French*. Otherwise, an International Driving Permit is not formally required but if you don't have one, you are supposed to have a translation in French from a certified translator, which is probably just as troublesome to obtain.

Rules for longer stays and for licenses issued by EU member states and associated countries differ.